# How to fix use of undeclared identifier 'AppDelegate' in Swift project with Objective c++

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c++

I have working swift and objective c++ project. If I use Appdelegate in Objective c++(.mm) file I am getting an error like:

```
/Projects/Controllers/BalanceCheck/BalanceCheckVC.mm:17:19: error: expected expression
    (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
                    ^
```

In header file OpenCVWrapper.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface OpenCVWrapper : NSObject
+ (NSString *)openCVVersionString;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

in OpenCVWrapper.mm file

```
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

@implementation OpenCVWrapper

+ (NSString *)openCVVersionString {

    //ERROR
    AppDelegate* testAppdel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OpenCV Version %s",  CV_VERSION];
}

@end
```

What I have done already:
Bridging header already included

Comment: this one works for me... `+(AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate
{
 return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}`

Comment: Is `AppDelegate` the problem or `UIApplication`? `UIApplication` is part of UIKit. Do you import UIKit?